# Modifying a set while iterating over it

Tags: python, set, iteration, sage

I would like to iterate over a set while I'm deleting
items from it. There are similar questions for [deleting
one item at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551334/delete-items-from-a-set-while-iterating-over-it) or for [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python), but they do
not work for my case.

The code follows; I iterate over a
set `ZN` and in the end of the iteration I'm removing a 
few items (the ones belonging to the set `temp`). But the
iteration is still happening over the "original" ZN.

How can I modify this code to change the set ZN while
I'm iterating over it?

```
def CyclotomicCosets(q,n):
    N=q^n-1
    ZN=set(range(N))
    Cosets=[]
    for i in ZN:
        tmp=set([])
        for j in range(n):
            tmp.add( i*(q^j) %N)
        Cosets.append(list(tmp))
        ZN=ZN.difference(tmp) # <------------ Does not do what I want
    return(Cosets)
```

Comment: Because ZN in **for i in ZN** is **set(range(N))** ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete items from a set while iterating over it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551334/delete-items-from-a-set-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop and `.pop()` values to process from the set:

```
def CyclotomicCosets(q, n):
    N = q ^ n - 1
    ZN = set(range(N))
    Cosets = []
    while ZN:
        i = ZN.pop()
        tmp = {i * (q ^ j) % N for j in range(n)}
        Cosets.append(list(tmp))
        ZN -= tmp
    return Cosets
```

Note that I replaced your inner `for` loop with a set comprehension to make it a little faster and more compact. These were introduced in Python 2.7 and Python 3, in earlier versions of python you can use a generator expression instead:

```
tmp = set(i * (q ^ j) % N for j in range(n))
```

Your original mistake was to *replace* `ZN` rather than update it:

```
ZN=ZN.difference(tmp)
```

This did not alter the original set you were using in the `for` loop. Rather, you are creating a *new* set and point the `ZN` reference to that.

However, you cannot modify a `set` while iterating over it, so even an in-place difference would not have worked; you would have to use `ZN -= tmp` or `ZN.difference_update(tmp)` but that would lead to exceptions instead:

```
>>> ZN = set(range(3))
>>> for i in ZN:
...     ZN -= set([2])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

The corrected code gives:

```
>>> CyclotomicCosets(3, 5)
[[0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 5], [0, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Alternatively, loop over `range(N)` instead, and keep a set of values you've already processed:

```
def CyclotomicCosets(q, n):
    N = q ^ n - 1
    Cosets = []
    seen = set()
    for i in range(N):
        if i in seen: continue
        tmp = {i * (q ^ j) % N for j in range(n)}
        Cosets.append(list(tmp))
        seen |= tmp
    return Cosets
```

Comment: Thank you! Copy-pasting your suggested code gave me:
`Syntax Error:
            Cosets.append(list(tmp))`

Comment: @geo909: What version of Python? I used a set comprehension, which is only available in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

Comment: To be honest I am using sage ("notebook" browser interface, accessing my university's sage via my browser), where you essentially are coding in python with extra math libraries (I guess, I'm quite new to coding and this). I can see that the sage version is 4.3 (dec 2009) but for the life of it I cannot find a way to get the python version  through the notebook interface. On another note, I changed the code a bit so that it works for me, I'll update my question..

Comment: Btw voting up requires more reputation than I have, sorry :)

Comment: Sage 4.3 is quite old, and uses Python 2.6.4, I believe.  I recommend that @geo909 update to the latest Sage, which uses 2.7, and has a TON of newer functionality... though if s/he has some custom code maybe that will be problematic.