# Remove all elements from a set greater than a number

Tags: python, set

As the title says, I want to remove all the elements of a set greater than some number. So if the number was 5 then {1,2,10} would become {1,2}.

I tried doing

```
myset = {1,2,10}

for i in myset:
  if i>5:
    myset.remove(i)
```

but I get RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration.
Evidently I need to do something different to make this work for sets, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) help at all?

Comment: No, since I can't use the same list comprehension commands for sets. The code in my question works if I use a list, for instance, but not for sets.

Comment: Those are some very strong assertions. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Can you create a new set? A common way to solve the problem is `myset = {i for i in myset if i > 5}`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551334/delete-items-from-a-set-while-iterating-over-it